Trying to authenticate using custom domain through Gmail
I set up a custom domain for our PTA (roosevelt-pta.org) using namecheap.com.  We needed more professional email addresses than what was available through gmail, so I set some up for all of our board members using siteground.com (president@roosevelt-pta.org, etc.) and connected them to the best gmail addresses available.  Now we log into our PTA gmail accounts, and when we send emails from those accounts, it appears to the recipient that they were sent from the @roosevelt-pta.org addresses.  People send emails to our @roosevelt-pta.org addresses and we receive them in our PTA gmail inboxes.
That part is all working well!  However, when we send emails they are showing up to the recipient with the warning:  "Be careful with this message. The sender hasn't authenticated this message so Gmail can't verify that it actually came from them."
I tried updating/verifying the SPF record in the advanced DNS:  v=spf1 a mx include:roosevelt-pta.org.spf.auto.dnssmarthost.net ~all
I realized that the DKIM record exceeded the character limit for namecheap, so I split it into 2 records.
First:  v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC70r1MXRV/5qzs2U5L6Z1Z0/1/IumncIk3DKBdxuxLeN/CiPL8r3UCNrri9ccm8y9e7ur5A4UYNSdzm52Wb/1k/AwFpw3OtK5SWeX9nMYkVaw2WFPA7qudlk1k6Abzi3b9v2nmozgDmOQCLJOMoaU1Ec
Second:  C5BYBZY9H7dmMdqlnCOwIDAQAB
I added a DMARC record:  v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:president@roosevelt-pta.org; ruf=mailto:president@roosevelt-pta.org; pct=100
What am I missing?  Why are they still coming through with the "not authenticated" warning? I'm totally new to this and any guidance would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

This is a very old Super User thread, nevertheless I wonder if it might still be relevant: Using a 410 character DKIM TXT record on namecheap.

Try adding an additional SPF record include:_spf.google.com so it now reads
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:roosevelt-pta.org.spf.auto.dnssmarthost.net ~all

This worked!!  Thank you so much!

Happy Dance! :o)
